# Solving a simultaneous equation through code

Tags: algorithm, math, equation

This seems like an incredibly simple and silly question to ask, but everything I've found about it has been too complex for me to understand.

I have these two very basic simultaneous equations:

```
X = 2x + 2z
Y = z - x
```

Given that I know both X and Y, how would I go about finding x and z? It's very easy to do it by hand, but I have no idea how this would be done in code.

Comment: What language are you planning on using, some languages are more suited to this sort of task than others.

Comment: How do you do it by hand? Can you try to write it down as generically as possible?

Comment: Do you need to solve arbitrary linear equations?

Comment: By hand and by code are two very different things when it comes to simultaneous equations, or atleast to do it efficiently.  I would honestly suggest using a language such as R or Matlab to solve this kind of thing because they are specifically designed for it.  If not then you could just try progrmming a substitution and elimination way of doing it.

Comment: @assylias:
I have to go, but I will post later. I use te substitution method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> This seems like an incredibly simple and silly question to ask

Not at all. This is a very good question, and it has unfortunately a complex answer. Let's solve

```
a * x + b * y = u
c * x + d * y = v
```

I stick to the 2x2 case here. More complex cases will require you to use a library.

The first thing to note is that [Cramer formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) are not good to use. When you compute the determinant

```
a * d - b * c
```

as soon as you have `a * d ~ b * c`, then you have [catastrophic cancellation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance). This case is typical, and you *must* guard against it.

The best tradeoff between simplicity / stability is [partial pivoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element#Partial_and_complete_pivoting). Suppose that `|a| > |c|`. Then the system is equivalent to

```
a * c/a * x + bc/a * y = uc/a
      c * x +    d * y = v
```

which is

```
cx + bc/a * y = uc/a
cx +       dy = v
```

and now, substracting the first to the second yields

```
cx +       bc/a * y = uc/a
     (d - bc/a) * y = v - uc/a
```

which is now straightforward to solve: `y = (v - uc/a) / (d - bc/a)` and `x = (uc/a - bc/a * y) / c`. Computing `d - bc/a` is stabler than `ad - bc`, because we divide by the biggest number (it is not very obvious, but it holds -- do the computation with very close coefficients, you'll see why it works).

Now, if `|c| > |a|`, you just swap the rows and proceed similarly.

In code (please check the Python syntax):

```
def solve(a, b, c, d, u, v):
    if abs(a) > abs(c):
         f = u * c / a
         g = b * c / a
         y = (v - f) / (d - g)
         return ((f - g * y) / c, y)
    else
         f = v * a / c
         g = d * a / c
         x = (u - f) / (b - g)
         return (x, (f - g * x) / a)
```

You can use full pivoting (requires you to swap x and y so that the first division is always by the largest coefficient), but this is more cumbersome to write, and almost never required for the 2x2 case.

For the n x n case, all the pivoting stuff is encapsulated into the [LU decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition), and you should use a library for this.

Comment: Thanks for the enormous help, but I will admit that much of the math in there is out of my scope of understanding. I did actually manage to solve it by hand:

'x = (X - 2Y)/4' and 
'z = Y + (X - 2Y)/4'

Answer (score 2):

@Alexandre , you missed one condition..
Here is the final code

```
void SolveLinearEquations (float a,float b,float c,float d,float u,float v, float &x, float &y)
{
float f;
float g;
if (abs(a) > abs(c))
{
     f = u * c / a;
     g = b * c / a;
     y = (v - f) / (d - g);
     if(c != 0)
        x = (f - g * y) / c;
     else
        x = (u - b * y)/a;
}
else
{
    f = v * a / c;
     g = d * a / c;
     x = (u - f) / (b - g);
     if (a != 0)
        y = (f - g * x) / a ;
     else
        y = (v - d * x)/c;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(1)  ax + by = c    
(2)  dx + dy = f

(3)1*d     adx + bdy  = cd
(4)2*b     abx + bdy  = fb

(3)-(4)   adx - abx  = cd - fb

          x(ad-ab) = cd - fb


          x = (c*d - f*b)/(a*d-a*b) //use this equation for x



ax + by = c
     by = c - ax

     y = (c - a*x)/b    //use this equation for y
```

Comment: The following might be better for most people:

Answer (score 0):

The following function might be useful for some:

```
function solve(s1,s2){    //only works if coefficients > 0

   str=s1 + " " +s2
   str=str.replace(/[^0123456789.-]/g, ' ') //eliminate letters
   str=str.replace( /\s\s+/g, ' ' )         //no double spaces


   var n=str.split(" ");            //put into an array
   var a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3,e=4,f=5      //see what were doing
   var x = ( n[c]*n[e] -n[b]*n[f])/(n[a]*n[e] - n[b]*n[d])
   var y= (n[c]-n[a]*x)/n[b]

   return({x:x, y:y})
}
```

To use:

```
result=solve("12x +  2y =32", "9x -5y=55")
alert (result.x+" ----- "+result.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm to sove: Ax + By = C, Dx + Ey = F

START

```
1)  PRINT "Enter A"
2)  INPUT A
3)  PRINT "Enter B"
4)  INPUT B
5)  PRINT "Enter C"
6)  INPUT C
7)  PRINT "Enter D"
8)  INPUT D
9)  PRINT "Enter E"
10) INPUT E
11) PRINT "Enter F"
21) INPUT F

22) detS <-- AE - BC
22) detX <-- CE - BF
24) detY <-- AF - CD

25) x <-- detX / detS
26) y <-- detY / detS

27) PRINT x, y
```

END