# Non-trivial eigenvectors of a 2*2 matrix in code

Tags: c, math, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I am trying to write a function in C which returns the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 2x2 matrix (looking for the eigen-values/vectors programatically). I've no problem with the eigenvalues which is fairly straightforward. But struggle with the eigenvectors, which is essentially solved by a system of simultaneous equations.

If I try a method such as: [Solving a simultaneous equation through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609107/solving-a-simultaneous-equation-through-code)
this gives me a trivial solutions ([0,0]), as u=0 and v=0, in the case of eigenvectors.

eg. if my matrix is MAT = [[3,2],[2,1]], ie. a=3, b=2, c=2 and d=1, and u=0 and v=0, the equations suggested in the above link y = (v - uc/a) / (d - bc/a) and x = (uc/a - bc/a * y) / c, will equate to the solution [0,0], ie. the trivial solution.

Also, this seemingly provides an answer but I can't generate an example which agrees with the equations on:
http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_04/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html

it also doesn't seem to cover all cases, **what about the case when b and c are not equal to zero**?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example where you get zero-valued eigenvectors?

Comment: If both of them are non-zero then both formulas vectors are same, don`t they? Did you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of a 2x2 matrix, there is a simple analytical solution.

Your function should implement the solution presented at [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20220529050926/http://www.math.harvard.edu/archive/21b_fall_04/exhibits/2dmatrices/index.html) link, with the three subcases. You may want to normalize the eigenvectors to unitary modulus as an additional step at the end.

Comment: But what about the case when both b and c are not equal to zero, what then?

Comment: that case belongs to the first case of the link, with `c` not zero. Or to the 2nd, with `b` not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the eigenvalues, the eigenvectors are easy to get.

I'd recommend an iterative method like [Jacobi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm) if your matrix is symmetric.