# Java calculate equations

Tags: java, math

Can any one tell me how to calculate the X and Y values in this equations

```
3X -3 = 6
```

and this

```
X + 5Y = something <-- This is just an example 
2X - 4Y = something <-- This is just an example
```

Using Java ?

Comment: How do you get the equation? Is it a string, or is it inside an ArrayList? Does the user input something over the console?

Comment: Have a look here, basically you want to solve a simultaneous equation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609107/solving-a-simultaneous-equation-through-code

Comment: How do you solve them without Java?  The first one would be symbolic algebra; the second one requires simultaneous equations and linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi) :

```
public static void main (final String args[])
{
    //Your equation (x and y)
    RealMatrix coefficients = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] { { 1,5 }, {2,-4} }, false);
    DecompositionSolver solver = new LUDecomposition(coefficients).getSolver();

    //Result of equation
    RealVector constants = new ArrayRealVector(new double[] { 27,-21 }, false);
    RealVector solution = solver.solve(constants);

    System.out.println("X = " + solution.getEntry(0));
    System.out.println("Y = " + solution.getEntry(1));
}
```