# Get the X,Y coordinate at the edge of a rhombus, based on the rhombus' width and angle

Tags: math, processing, trigonometry

[image]

I'm developing a [Processing](http://www.processing.org) sketch that, given a certain angle, draws a dot at the edge of a rhombus.

I know the width of the rhombus, and its position, but I'm not sure how to calculate the x-y coordinates of a dot resting at its edge.

Are there any elegant solutions for this problem? Any help in pseudocode would be welcomed.

Comment: Just so you know, [Processing is not the same as Java](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java).

Comment: You're perfectly right. I mentioned Java, as Processing might not be known by all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's square side length is `A`, half-length is `H = A/2`. Angle `Theta`. Intersection point P.
All coordinates are relative to the square center.

Rotate square by `-Pi/4`, angle `Alpha = Theta - Pi/4`

```
if Alpha lies in range -Pi/4..Pi/4, then intersection point P' = (H, H*Tan(Alpha))
if Alpha lies in range Pi/4..3*Pi/4, then P' = (H*Cotangent(Alpha), H)
if Alpha lies in range 3*Pi/4..5*Pi/4, then P' = (-H, -H*Tan(Alpha))
if Alpha lies in range 5*Pi/4..7*Pi/4, then P' = (-H*Cotangent(Alpha), -H)
```

Then rotate point `P'` back by `Pi/4`:

```
S = Sqrt(2)/2
P.X = S * (P'.X - P'.Y)
P.Y = S * (P'.X + P'.Y)
```

Example (data like your sketch):

```
A = 200, Theta = 5*Pi/12  
H = 200/2 = 100, Alpha =Theta-Pi/4 = Pi/6
P'.X = H = 100
P'.Y = H * Tan(Alpha) = 100 * Tan(Pi/6) ~= 57.7

S = 0.707
P.X = 0.707 * (100 - 57.7) = 30
P.Y = 0.707 * (100 + 57.7) = 111
```

Comment: what notation is P' = (H, Tan(Alpha)), P' = (Cotangent(Alpha), H), etc.?

Comment: P' = (X, Y) - rotated point. Tan(Alpha) - tangent function. Note edit - multiplication by H is added

Answer (score 2):

Based on your image, you want to find the intersection of two equations, that of the line at angle θ, and that of the side of the square with which it intersects.

Assuming the size of your square is `n`, the equation of the square is `y=±(n*(√2/2))±x` (by Pythagoras' theorem). The equation for the side you intersect in your image is `y=n*(√2/2)-x`.

The equation of the radial line can be calculated using trigonometry to be `y=tan(θ)*x`, with θ expressed in radians.

You can then solve this as a [simultaneous equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609107/solving-a-simultaneous-equation-through-code) to determine the intersection. Please note that it will intersect with both sides of the square (both above and below), so if you only want the one you will have to choose the equation for the correct side of the square. Also guard against the case where θ is π/2, as tan(π/2) is undefined. You can easily work out that case, as x=0 and so it will always intersect at `y=±(n*(√2/2))`.

In your example, the intersection occurs when `x*(1+tan(θ))=n*(√n/n)`, or `x=(n*(√n/n))/(1+tan(θ))`. You can calculate that, plug it back into y and that is your (x,y) intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a circle with a larger radius that will intersect your rhombus at the points you want. One way to draw at that location is to use a nested coordinate system that you translate and rotate. All you need to know is the radius and the angle.

Here's a very basic example:

```
float angle = radians(-80.31);
float radius = 128; 

float centerX,centerY;
void setup(){
  size(320,320);
  noFill();
  rectMode(CENTER);

  centerX = width * 0.5;
  centerY = height * 0.5;
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  noFill();
  //small circle
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,210,210);
  rhombus(centerX,centerY,210);
  //large circle
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,radius * 2,radius * 2);

  //line at angle
  pushMatrix();
    translate(centerX,centerY);
    rotate(angle);
    stroke(162,42,32);
    line(0,0,radius,0);
  popMatrix();

  //debug
  fill(0);
  text("angle: " + degrees(angle),10,15);
}
void rhombus(float x,float y,float size){
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x,y);
  rotate(radians(45));
  rect(0,0,size,size);
  popMatrix();
}
void mouseDragged(){
  angle = atan2(centerY-mouseY,centerX-mouseX)+PI;
}
```

You can try a demo here(you can drag the mouse to change the angle):

```js
var angle;
var radius = 128; 

var centerX,centerY;
function setup(){
  createCanvas(320,320);
  noFill();
  rectMode(CENTER);
  
  angle = radians(-80.31);
  centerX = width * 0.5;
  centerY = height * 0.5;
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  noFill();
  //small circle
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,210,210);
  rhombus(centerX,centerY,210);
  //large circle
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,radius * 2,radius * 2);
  
  //line at angle
  push();
    translate(centerX,centerY);
    rotate(angle);
    stroke(162,42,32);
    line(0,0,radius,0);
  pop();
  
  //debug
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  text("angle: " + degrees(angle),10,15);
}
function rhombus(x,y,size){
  push();
  translate(x,y);
  rotate(radians(45));
  rect(0,0,size,size);
  pop();
}
function mouseDragged(){
  angle = atan2(centerY-mouseY,centerX-mouseX)+PI;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to calculate the position, you can use the polar to cartesian coordinate conversion formula:

```
x = cos(angle) * radius
y = sin(angle) * radius
```

Here's an example using that. Note that drawing is done from the centre, therefore the centre coordinates are added to the above:

```
float angle = radians(-80.31);
float radius = 128; 

float centerX,centerY;
void setup(){
  size(320,320);
  noFill();
  rectMode(CENTER);

  centerX = width * 0.5;
  centerY = height * 0.5;
}
void draw(){
  background(255);
  noFill();
  //small circle
  strokeWeight(1);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,210,210);
  rhombus(centerX,centerY,210);
  //large circle
  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(95,105,120);
  ellipse(centerX,centerY,radius * 2,radius * 2);

  //line at angle
  float x = centerX+(cos(angle) * radius);
  float y = centerX+(sin(angle) * radius);
  stroke(162,42,32);
  line(centerX,centerY,x,y);

  //debug
  fill(0);
  text("angle: " + degrees(angle),10,15);
}
void rhombus(float x,float y,float size){
  pushMatrix();
  translate(x,y);
  rotate(radians(45));
  rect(0,0,size,size);
  popMatrix();
}
void mouseDragged(){
  angle = atan2(centerY-mouseY,centerX-mouseX)+PI;
}
```

Another option would be using transformation matrices